# Styleborder's value for a subtitle with transparent dark background (mostly used in Youtube videos)

Tags: css, subtitle

I'm trying to change background of my .ass subtitle file. This format of subtitle has a property named "Styleborder" and I changed its value from 1 to 3, so it took black background, but I want more transparent black style, just like this one in here:
[image: The first subtitle above which has more transparent dark background is what I want to set.]

And here is the code:

- [Script Info]
  ; This is an Advanced Sub Station Alpha v4+ script.
  Title: friends.s01e02.720p.bluray.x264--sujaidr
  ScriptType: v4.00+
  Collisions: Normal
  PlayDepth: 0
  Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour,
  Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow,
  Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
  Style: Default,Arial,20,&H00FFFFFF,&H0300FFFF,&H00000000,&H02000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,3,2,1,2,10,10,10,1
  [Events]
  Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
  Dialogue: 0,0:00:02.87,0:00:04.29,Default,,0,0,0,,What you guys don't understand is...

Since it uses only Format and Style property and it's not really a .css code, I add a screenshot of this .ass subtitle file:"
[image: .ass subtitle with black background]

Comment: Can you post your code with your question? This way we can see what you've tried already.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it right away, because this way it would be more clear to insert a compatible code into it. It doesn't have functioned css code, it's based on some properties under Format part.

Comment: Let me know when you've updated your question!

Comment: Ok, I did, Thank you. But I guess I have to rewrite its code, because the original code is only a .ass file with Style property that contains 23 items!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have experience with .ass. Can't help you further I think.

Answer (score 0):

Set OutlineColour with alpha channel = &H80000000 for example